# Proof verification: Is the Frobenius endomorphism is an automorphism when a ring is finite and an integral domain?

Tags: proof-verification, ring-theory

I was thinking about when the Frobenius endomorphism is an automorphism. It is a well known fact that if you are taking the Frobenius endomorphism over a finite field such that $Char(F) = p$, then the mapping is also an [automorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2484972/when-is-the-frobenius-endomorphism-an-automorphism).

Could the requirement be loosened to a finite integral domain with characteristic $p$ instead? The below argument and its mistakes (if any, which is why I posted this on MSE) are solely mine. Does it hold?

In a finite set, a injective map is also a surjective one, so it only suffices to prove one. We shall prove that the Frobenius endomorphism is a injective map by a proof by contradiction.

Let $R$ be a finite ring with characteristic $p$ with the property that it is an integral domain. The Frobenius endomorphism will be denoted by $\phi$.

If $\phi$ wasn't injective, then there $\exists$ $a,b \in R$ where $a \ne b$ and $ a, b \ne 0$ such that $\phi(a) = \phi(b)$. This would mean that $a^p$ = $b^p$.

For some  $n$ where  $1 < n <p $, $a^n = b^n$. For any number smaller than $n$, let's say $m$, $a^m \ne b^m$. The intuition in this step is that if you  start out with $a \ne b$ and end up with $a^p = b^p$, then at some point you are going to wind up having  $a^n = b^n$.

Since $p = kn + m$ where $m < n$, we have $a^{kn+m} = b^{kn+m}$, then $a^{kn}a^m = b^{kn}b^m $. Since $a^n = b^n$, $a^{kn} = b^{kn}$. Thus $a^{kn}a^m = a^{kn}b^m \rightarrow a^m = b^m$ in an integral domain, which is a contradiction!

Are there any errors in the proof? I am worried about the the claim that there is some $m < p$ where $a^m \ne b^m $ even though I think it's true.

I can't find any resources online on how the Frobenius endomorphism behaves in an integral domain. If anyone would also be kind enough to point me to more resources, I'd be grateful.

Comment: The point is that a finite integral domain is a field.

Comment: Wow, I have been going in circles all along. That is news to me though, I will go read up on that.

Comment: It is not a difficult proof. You will find several versions of it on this site.